# PHP. Получить бб-теги из текста регуляркой. Что не так?

Tags: php

Есть пример текста:

> [BB1:description]data[/BB1] asdfasf [BB2]data[/BB2] asfasfasf [BB3:description]data [BB4]data[/BB4] asfasfasf [/BB3] asfasfasf

Нужно из него дернуть теги (заголовки), их содержимое и описание.

Написал:

```
$text = '[BB1:description]data[/BB1] asdfasf [BB2]data[/BB2] asfasfasf [BB3:description]data [BB4]data[/BB4] asfasfasf [/BB3] asfasfasf ';
$pattern = "/\[(\w+)(?:[\:]([\w]+))?\](.*)\[\/\1\]/iu";
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

На regex101.com все работает. В пхп, получаю:

> Array
>   (
>   [0] => Array
>   (
>   )
>
> [1] => Array
>   (
>   )
>
> [2] => Array
>   (
>   )
>
> [3] => Array
>   (
>   )
>
> )

Почему пустой вывод? Что не так?

Comment: Может просто не стоит "получать bb-теги из текста регуляркой"? А вместо этого сделать нормально - парсингом?

Comment: Парсингом оно, конечно, верней... но регуляркой интересней! Так или иначе, вопрос решен: "/\[(\w+)(?:[\:]([\w]+))?\](.*)\[\/\\1\]/iu" (просто нужно было два слеша перед 1, а не один = \\1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После некоторых экспериментов нашлось решение:

```
"/\[(\w+)(?:[\:]([\w]+))?\](.*)\[\/\\1\]/iu"
```

(два слеша, вместо одного = \\1)